# Keyboard layout of terminal through X11 ssh tunnel is wrong - how to fix?

Tags: ssh, keyboard-layout, tunnel

If I display a terminal over an ssh tunnel (X11 forwarding) to Xming on a Windows 10 PC, the keyboard setting is wrong. On the Ubuntu machine itself, the keyboard setting is correct. What puzzles me: if I check the keyboard settings with the usual commands on that terminal displayed on Xming, it all looks ok too. Just the keys do not match the configured language.

**Instead, the actual keymap seems to be "us" !!**

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, swiss german locale.

I am stumped. Can you give me a pointer?

ssh to Ubuntu:
/etc/default/keyboard

```
XKBMODEL="logicd"
XKBLAYOUT="ch"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

localectl status

```
   System Locale: LANG=de_CH.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: ch
      X11 Layout: ch
       X11 Model: logicd
```

Then open terminator or xterm, the window is displayed on by Xming on the PC:

localectl status

```
   System Locale: LANG=de_CH.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: ch
      X11 Layout: ch
       X11 Model: logicd
```

setxkbmap -query

```
rules:      xorg
model:      pc105
layout:     de_CH
```

setxkbmap -query | awk -F"(,|[ ]+)" '/layout:/ { print $2 }'

```
de_CH
```

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources | grep -Po "'[[:alpha:]]+')" | sed -ne "s/['|)]//g;$(($current_layout+1))p"

```
ch
```

setxkbmap -print -verbose 10

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/xorg...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg...
Success.
Applied rules from xorg:
rules:      xorg
model:      pc105
layout:     de_CH
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   xfree86+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+de_CH+inet(pc105)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "xfree86+aliases(qwerty)"   };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+de_CH+inet(pc105)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
```

.. and so on..
All commands insists that I have the **ch** mapping active.

But I definitively have the **us** mapping active.

Examples:

```
- on keyboard produces in xterm /
? on keyboard produces in xterm _
! on keyboard produces in xterm }
& on keyboard produces in xterm ^
```

Anyone has a clue how I can set up the correct keymap? 
As I mentioned before, the keymap is correct in any other situation.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: I guess noone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but later I found it is not a host problem, instead a client-side problem.

I was using OSX and `xer` on terminal shown wrong keyboard catch.

You can check some discussions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216982/remote-x11-applications-have-wrong-keyboard-mappings-local-osx-remote-linux).